# Как перечислить варианты и в этом же предложении выбрать один из них?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

Я так сделал:

> Из вариантов: сильнейшая стрессоустойчивость Григория или, как обычно бывает, обыденное стечение других обстоятельств – конечно на второе рассчитываем.

Правильно ли по пунктуации? Как ещё можно было бы сконструировать это предложение (в одном).

Comment: Если такую конструкцию и слепить, она будет не иначе как саморазрушающейся. Может быть «второе» на «второй» заменить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из вариантов — сильнейшая стрессоустойчивость Григория или, как часто бывает, обыденное стечение других обстоятельств – разумеется, на второе рассчитываем.

Перечисление лучше дать вставкой, отделённой *равноценными* паузами. Замена «обычно» на «часто» желательна при нежелательном скоплении трёх *бы*.

Comment: 1) два тире - присоединительный (вставочный) вариант для однородного ряда, а нам важно именно его содержание, поэтому желательно двоеточие. 2) Конечно здесь - вводное слово, а не частица (с. словарь), необходимо обособление.

Comment: 3) Я не уверена, что при вставке можно использовать форму среднего рода "на второе". Получается: из вариантов на второе рассчитываем. 4) В конце предложения  структура неудобна для чтения. Логически надо выделить слово "второй", поставив его в конец фразы.

Comment: Я даже уверен, что это грамматически нельзя: род должен согласовываться в пределах основного высказывания и не может привязываться к элементам вставки.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь очень длинное описание вариантов, поэтому придётся их разграничить и обозначить более "сильными" средствами:

> Из вариантов: а) сильнейшая стрессоустойчивость Григория и б)
>   обыденное стечение других обстоятельств (как это обычно бывает) –
>   конечно же, рассчитываем на втор**ой**.

Answer (score 2):

Из вариантов: сильнейшая стрессоустойчивость Григория **или же обыкновенное стечение других обстоятельств** – по преимществу рассчитываем на второй.

1) Выбор **обыденный/обыкновенный** делается по контексту.

2) ***Как это часто бывает*** – неинформативный оборот.

3) Частица ***ЖЕ*** усиливает разделительное значение.

4) ***Конечно*** – вводное слово, требующее обособления; лучше заменить на более "энергичное" наречие.